# Are answers that add minor details to other answers allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with answers that build heavily (if not copied outright) on an existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/what-to-do-with-answers-that-build-heavily-if-not-copied-outright-on-an-existi)

I spotted [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1023241/nusrat) who copy-pastes other answers and adds just a little bit more information, like a short code snippet. Technically the answer is slightly more informative, but it would have been better to just edit the existing answer.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619560/getting-sql-error-1064-in-cakephp/8133335#8133335) the most obvious case where the answer is practically the same; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180655/change-admin-layout-in-cakephp/8238608#8238608) there are just minor additions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013392/inline-style-in-cakephp/8356479#8356479) even has the exact same opening paragraph.

Should these kind of answers be flagged or are they ok?

Comment: "but it would have been better to just edit the existing answer." Bit tricky sometimes, since you're not supposed to change the meaning of the original answer.

Comment: I disagree strongly that you should edit existing answers in the manner suggested here. I also think it's bad form to copy-and-paste someone else's answer; One should simply say, "I like the answer by X, and here's more relevant info..."

Comment: If you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013392/inline-style-in-cakephp/8356479#8356479), would it not have been ok to just add that code example to the existing answer?

Comment: Actually, I think the particular user being noted here isn't even "adding" anything to the answers; In a couple cases he's just modifying inconsequential details. He's definitely not improving upon them. One of his answers (the only one that appears original) also doesn't make any sense related to the question.

Comment: @Juhana As for the example where you ask if it would be OK to just edit that into the answer: *Absolutely not*, and that answer is a great example of why not: The code that nusrat posted actually *contradicts* the above answerer's ultimate recommendation.

Comment: @Juhana FYI, the first answer you link to has been removed.