# Ask, copy existing answer, paste as new answer, accept it: is this abuse of the system?

Tags: support, plagiarism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/handling-answers-that-build-heavily-on-or-are-copied-outright-from-existing-an)

I posted an answer to [Silverlight detect wether loosing focus is because tab is pressed or mouse is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643122/silverlight-detect-wether-loosing-focus-is-because-tab-is-pressed-or-mouse-is-cl).

The asker initially accepted my answer, and I got reputation. Later, he posted an answer of his own, describing the same thing a little differently and thanking me, and moved the acceptance to it. I lost reputation and got nothing. Is this abuse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like the OP's self-accepted answer is different enough from yours to warrant a separate answer.  You don't get any reputation points for accepting your own answer (in fact, he lost two points for unaccepting yours in this case), so there's no reputation incentive to "gaming" the system in this way.  I think the only motivation here was to have the most complete and correct answer possible to the question.