# Ask a question. Answer it. OP just copies my answer as their own

Tags: discussion, support, answers, declined-flags, original-poster

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658373/561731)

[OPs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8675102/561731) (**now** 10k only)
[OPs Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8675102/revisions)

All the OP did was copy my answer as their own. How is that right?

What can I do?

---

And now the OP accepted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658365/561731) which did not even help them!

---

And now a mod **declined** my flag:

[image]

Comment: That's not right. But I would say "move on". The OP might gather some downvotes and you perhaps some upvotes by bringing it to our attention. Not much more that can be done I think.

Comment: @Bart The OP downvoted all the answers (i know this because look at my comment to the accepted answer) then when The OP accepted the answer, he/she reversed their vote

Comment: Well, if the behavior it truly eratic and unacceptable, just flag the question for moderator attention and explain the issue. (Or perhaps a Mod will pick it up here). And if he shows strange voting behavior, perhaps the system will catch and correct it anyway (although I'm not sure about this particular instance).

Comment: @Bart I have flagged it.

Comment: @Bart my flag was declined....

Comment: You merely flagged it "not an answer"? You gave no further explanation?

Comment: @Bart well now im going to reflag and link this meta question...

Comment: @Bart lol the OP deleted their answer.

Comment: Are you mad because he copied the approach from your answer, or because he did so without attribution?

Comment: @mario the OP did so with naming my name. But then did not accept the answer that did help them. Use my approach as much as you want, that was the idea ^_^ I answered so that the OP **would** use it.

Comment: per my [past experience](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109383/was-it-a-mistake-to-flag-these-answers), **not-an-answer flag sucks in all but simplest cases** -- and your is simple but not simple enough, really. For those willing to avoid playing russian roulette with their flag weight I'd rather recommend flagging as "other" with more detailed explanation what was wrong. Guy who advised that to me got 50 rep bounty and as time passes I feel more and more that I underpaid him :)

Comment: Well, while that might loook unappreciative, this is actually a desired approach. If OP tailored a solution to his specific problem, then it's welcome he publishes that as well.

Comment: @mario not if it is the exact same thing!

Comment: @BilltheLizard :'( I shall survive, but that is kind of annoying....

Comment: I'm sorry about the declined flag.  That looked like a reasonable answer, so your "not an answer" flag should have been "other" with a bit of explanation.  Since the code the OP posted as an answer *was* exactly the same as yours originally, he should have just upvoted/accepted your answer instead of leaving a redundant answer.  The redundant answer should have been deleted, and now is.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I flagged it when it was the same code. I did not even know he changed it until later.... Now I know to **always** use `other`.....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA If it's something that we're conditioned to automatically recognize as not an answer ("thanks" or "I have the same problem...") then "not an answer" is pretty safe.  With anything else you are better off breaking it down for us.

Comment: @BilltheLizard hehe now I know for most of my future flags ^_^

Comment: See also [Ask, copy existing answer, paste as new answer, accept it: is this abuse of the system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117432/ask-copy-existing-answer-paste-as-new-answer-accept-it-is-this-abuse-of-the), [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112084/131713) and numerous others

Answer (score 2):

I think that answer can just be down-voted as it is not useful at all.
The OP claims his answer is different, but the code does the same thing as the code shown in yours.

As that answer has a negative score, 20k users can vote to delete it. I am not sure that flagging it for moderator's attention would have any effect; that answer can be taken care from the community.

If the OP keeps doing that, he shows he doesn't understand how Stack Exchange sites work. I am not sure of the reason of pretending the two answers are different. Maybe the OP thinks that who ask the question gain reputation in accepting their own answer; if that is the case, it shows the OP doesn't understand well how Stack Exchange works.