# Explanation why a flag was declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018429/usb-clear-endpoint-feature/1147041#1147041) as not an answer. It was declined by a mod with the reason:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

When I read the OP and the answers and then finally the item I flagged, I just don't see why it was not removed.  It is a comment by the original user with absolutely no explanation of what the final problem was or how it was resolved.

I totally understand that the mods review a tons of flags everyday and maybe I just am not awake yet, but this just doesn't seem like it should be kept as an answer to the question.

Am I missing something? Should I just flag it again as other with an explanation?

Comment: I converted that answer to be an edit to the question, since the OP accepted another answer. Still, it _was_ an answer to the question, if only to say that 'there was no problem here, sorry'. However, I'm not sure why it didn't get converted when the question was closed, probably just a very busy day :)

Comment: @TimPost thanks for checking. I know you guys are busy with this stuff, I was just somewhat confused. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators do not always have the time to check fully whether or not an answer is or is not an answer.
It might have looks from the distance as a legit answer, so the mod marked it as such.

What I do is I use the `other` section to explain why I think the post should be changed, and it usually gets better results.

[image: other]

Comment: Er. I know mods don't have time to go in-depth, but if the flag is "not an answer" they should probably at least make the time to check if the post is or is not an answer

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I agree with you, but I have had this issue before, and using the `other` comment area helped.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek see my [question over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117511/155556)

Comment: See this comment in particular: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117511/ask-a-question-answer-it-op-just-copies-my-answer-as-their-own#comment307991_117511 (sorry for the multiple pinging) @MichaelMrozek

Comment: You can edit comments for 5 minutes, by the way :). And yes, I'm sure using "other" helps, and I recommend it too, but hopefully none of them are saying "I don't have time to determine if this NaA flag is right -- dismissed"

Comment: I've started flagging as other for what I consider Not an Answer answers too. Not an Answer tends to be judged very strictly, and that is the right way to do it. However, when something might be borderline, it's far better to flag as "Other" and explain in your own words what you think is wrong; that way, there can be no misunderstanding or confusion and even if the flag is declined, it's more likely to be declined as helpful as you've demonstrated good faith in your flagging.