# What is the reason for users to repeat answers?

Tags: discussion, fastest-gun

Since 2 weeks or so I am trying to follow Stack Overflow more frequently.

However, I am not an expert in an area. Therefore, I usually answer to questions that are quite easy. Those questions usually have fast answers and I give up if I see another answer with the same content (even if that answer is poorly constructed).

In the last answers I gave I usually see someone repeating my answer OR edited answer after I give my answer. Why people do that? And what should be done in these cases?

Comment: If it's close in time, they probably just were a bit slower typing, so that's nothing to worry about.

Comment: We are talking about 7-10 minutes. And, when you receive a new answer usually stackoverflow warns you in the top. I know that because one time I was elaborating an answer and stackoverflow provided that info and I stoped my answer.

Comment: Related: [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/handling-answers-that-build-heavily-on-or-are-copied-outright-from-existing-an)

Comment: Yeah, was kinda the same case. I understand that it is possible and nothing is "legaly" wrong. But morally it is wrong. Shouldn't exist some mechanism to fight it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why people do that?

Because they can. This is one of the strengths of StackOverflow over traditional forums - one can correct a post and expand on it.

In regards to why someone is repeating an answer - they may have posted at the same time as you and did not see your answer. It is possible that they have seen your answer and think they have a better one (better phrased, better explanation or example/s etc...).

Both of the above reasons are valid and normal.

> what should be done in these cases?

Nothing. This is how the system was designed to work.

Comment: So, I can answer a question like: Just add a String on your variable. And then when I see a better answer I can edit mine so it can be close to the other answer? I know the system was designed to act like this, but I belive that multiple answers will only confuse the person who made the question. Should I worry about that?

Comment: @Tiago - Yes, you _can_ answer like that, but shouldn't. You _should_ improve your question where possible to make it as good as possible. Don't worry about confusing the asker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql/40866162?noredirect=1#comment118145567_40866162 is a good example of the issue presented. Timestamps are far enough apart that the repeat answerers should've seen the accepted answer.