# Should we have a procedure for duplicate for answers also?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, duplicate-answers

I have gone through these two questions answered by Mike and CommonsWare. 
Mike has just copied and pasted CommonsWare's answer as-is *from another question*.
[Answer by Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829714/error-while-using-the-endlessadapter-in-android) and original Answer By [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588246/arrayadapterhashmap-with-commonsguy-endlessadapter-class).

So should there be any option of duplicate vote. Or we can just refer that it duplicate.

**I think he can comment with a Link instead of giving new answer**

**Updated**

Link given by me will not work now.as one duplicate question is already deleted by moderator when i flag this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/handling-answers-that-build-heavily-on-or-are-copied-outright-from-existing-an)

Comment: not exactly..:)

Comment: Whoops, missed the "feature-request" tag, my bad. Anyway, I don't think we need such a functionality, as we (as far as I know) already have a policy/procedtur about it.

Comment: deleting these type of post is best solution to reduce overhead from stackoverflow

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a procedure: flag the answer so a moderator can take action if it's needed.

In addition, you can:

- downvote the answer
- post a comment to politely point to the copy-paste and explain that this is not an encouraged behaviour.

And of course, if another answer is suitable, there is a chance that the question is a duplicate too, so you can vote to close it if warranted.

Answer (score 15):

There is a procedure: flag the answer so a moderator can take action if it's needed.

In addition, you can:

- downvote the answer
- post a comment to politely point to the copy-paste and explain that this is not an encouraged behaviour.

And of course, if another answer is suitable, there is a chance that the question is a duplicate too, so you can vote to close it if warranted.

---

*all joking aside...*

There are three scenarios I can think of

1 (one). Answers are trivial and therefore similar
2 (two). Answer is a dupe of the same user's answer
3 (three). Answer is copied directly from another user

**If the answer is *somewhat similar*** (as often happens with questions whose answers are trivial), please don't worry about it.  We have lots of users who obsess about this.  *"His answer for a regex that matches all words with more than five letters is exactly the same as mine!"*  Well, no offal, Sherlock.  In cases like this, just move on (preferrably), downvote (not even worth it), or move on.  Or you could just move on.  Moving on is best.

**If the answer is an exact copy of another answer by the same user**, don't worry about it.  The website will automatically flag these for moderator attention.

**If, as in this case, the answer was *a direct copy of another users' work,*** PLEASE flag it for moderator attention! That is unethical and an abuse of our users, and will **not** be tolerated.

Comment: I flagged this answer, since you clearly used your moderator hypno-ray to make Gamecat copy your answer 5 hours before you posted it.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar: I have dismissed your flag as "shut your face, snitch!"

Comment: You turned into a copycat for the first part of your answer :P.

Comment: @Won't:so that's what moderator do when we flag any answer :)

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad Shake our fists violently in the air, scream select words and ultimately decide what to do with it. All kidding aside? Duplicate answers usually result in a question being closed and merged, and at least one of the duplicate answers deleted. It really depends on if the questions are far enough apart to remain on their own.