# What to do about a user who is plagiarising answers from other sites to build up rep?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112084/handling-answers-that-build-heavily-on-or-are-copied-outright-from-existing-an)

I noticed a user on SO who seems to be copying and pasting answers from other sites without any attribution and presenting these as his own work. Presumably he's just doing this to build up rep. I've flagged a few of these plagiarised answers but I'm wondering if there is anything further I should do ?

Comment: It seems (once instance of) the particular case you're referring to contains copied content that is released under [a CC license which requires attribution](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/in/). So at the very least the answer should include that.

Comment: When it is plagiarised from stackoverflow, the asker also should have searched better and when it is plagiarised from an external site, then the answerer googled. Moreover, lot's of these external sites are forums, where you need to go through lots of posts, analyzing all of them, and then finding the conclusion, before you can answer here. Which I would rather call a 'literary study' then plagiarism. My point is, someone asked a question and got an answer. I could only imagine that copied answers form stackoverflow should be marked as 'possible duplicate of'. And include external references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a moderator flag with a custom reason and explain that there is a pattern of misbehaviour, if you haven't done so. This will lead to the moderators investigating the user's history, not just the specific flagged content.

In cases where there is a problematic user behaviour that is not apparent from just seeing one post, it's always a good idea to add some detail in the flag reason.

Comment: Thanks - I did mention that this seemed to be a pattern for this particular user in the last answer I flagged, but this was fairly recently and it hasn't been actioned by a mod yet.

Comment: Investigating that stuff takes time, and SO is a bit short-staffed right now as a few mods are unavailable. It'll probably be handled in some time.