# Etiquette for answering with the content of an existing answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Is it acceptable to copy and paste an existing answer, and make a minor change (such as one line of code), then submit as your own answer to the same question (with no credit)? I'm not talking about one liner answers for example with the name of a function to solve the problem. I mean something more like ~20 lines of code with example test input and output.

If I see an answer that [I think] needs a minor change I usually throw in a comment informing the poster.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: [Handling answers that build heavily on (or are copied outright from) existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112084/166025)

Comment: Thanks for the link, yeah more related than a duplicate I think because in that question credit is given.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it acceptable to copy and paste an existing answer, and make a
>   minor change (such as one line of code), then submit as your own
>   answer to the same question (with no credit)?

The system will not stop anyone in doing so, meaning there is no automated script to check that, but it is not acceptable (bordering illegal when explicit credit / acknowledgement is not given).

You may flag such answers and explain why you have flagged it. Mods can remove those answers. Keep in mind that it can be difficult to prove plagiarism. However, if an answer takes an idea from another answer, that is normally fine.

> If I see an answer that [I think] needs a minor change I usually throw
>   in a comment informing the poster.

This is usually the best approach. It helps in having one (or few) good answers which can help the OP and future visitors too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking more in terms of etiquette than the legal stuff, as you linked - answers are under the CC license anyway.

Comment: Not giving credit comes under bad etiquette. If you give credit and provide a similar answer then you are adding duplicate content (read waste) on Stack Exchange which again is not good.